# How to combine two data-frames by group and date

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, merge, combine

I'd like to combine two dataframes d1 and d2 in R. It should be grouped by "ID", but at the end there should only exist one column "date" so that further analysis are possible (It is important to know if the "number"-entry (d2) is linked to the "type"-entry (d1) or how close it is to it)

Lets say d1 and d2 is

```
d1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,2,2,2,3), 
                 sex = c("male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "female"),
                 date = c("2016-06-21 08:15:00", "2016-06-21 23:00:00",
                          "2017-04-19 07:15:00", "2017-04-20 07:15:00", "2017-04-20 08:15:00",
                          "2017-08-20 23:15:00" ),
                 type = c("horse", "snake", "horse", "horse", "monkey", "fish"))

d2 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3), 
                 date = c("2016-06-20 08:15:00", "2016-06-21 22:15:00", "2016-06-22 08:45:00",
                          "2017-04-19 07:15:00", "2017-04-19 09:30:00",
                          "2017-08-19 08:15:00", "2017-08-21 06:30:00"),
                 number = c(65,234,64,234,6243,23,243))
```

My desired output would be

```
d12 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                  sex = c(NA, "male", NA, "male", NA, "male", NA, "male", "male" , NA, "female", NA),
                  date = c("2016-06-20 08:15:00","2016-06-21 08:15:00", "2016-06-21 22:15:00", "2016-06-21 23:00:00", "2016-06-22 08:45:00",
                          "2017-04-19 07:15:00", "2017-04-19 09:30:00", "2017-04-20 07:15:00", "2017-04-20 08:15:00",
                          "2017-08-19 08:15:00", "2017-08-20 23:15:00", "2017-08-21 06:30:00" ),
                  type = c(NA, "horse", NA, "snake", NA, "horse", NA, "horse", "monkey", NA, "fish", NA),
                  number= c(65, NA, 234, NA, 64, 234, 6243, NA, NA, 23, NA, 243))
```

I tried doing this

```
d12 <- full_join(
  d1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(time=row_number()),
  d2 %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(time=row_number()),
by = c("ID", "time"))
```

But more or less I just added some columns, I don't really come closer to my desired output. I am very looking forward to your help.

Comment: @RonakShah I think that was misunderstanding from my side. What i meant is if they are chronologically linked. So therefore it would be good if I only have one column "date" which refers to both "type" and "number".

Comment: `d2` is missing a `sex` column. How do you create the second line of `d12`: `1   male 2016-06-20 08:15:00   <NA>     65`? The `date` doesn't match the first line of `d1`.

Comment: @MartinGal The mentioned dataframe was just an example. In the original one there are many columns in d2 but not in d1 and the other way round. It would not matter if there are NAs in the d12 instead. The second line of d12 is the first line of d1.

Comment: * of d2 (sorry)

Comment: @Franziska So for line 2 the column `sex` has to be empty? I'm sorry, but I still don't understand how the algorithm looks like for merging `d1` and `d2`.

Comment: @MartinGal Yes, for line 2 the column `sex` can be empty. There will be more empty cells because of this.  I just wanted to demonstrate that there are also columns in one dataframe which do not occur in the second dataframe. Maybe I'll complete them in a next step (it's obvious that `sex` for the same ID has to be the same). The main problem is that I don't know how to combine the `data` columns so that `type` and `number` is in the right order (in a next stept I want to analyse for example the amount of `number` two hours after a specific event `type`). Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still a little bit puzzled about this question. You could try

```r
library(dplyr)

d1 %>% 
  full_join(d2, by = c("ID", "date")) %>% 
  mutate(date = as.POSIXct(date)) %>% 
  arrange(ID, date) %>% 
  tibble() # this line isn't really necessary
```

This returns

```r
      ID sex    date                type   number
   <dbl> <chr>  <dttm>              <chr>   <dbl>
 1     1 NA     2016-06-20 08:15:00 NA         65
 2     1 male   2016-06-21 08:15:00 horse      NA
 3     1 NA     2016-06-21 22:15:00 NA        234
 4     1 male   2016-06-21 23:00:00 snake      NA
 5     1 NA     2016-06-22 08:45:00 NA         64
 6     2 male   2017-04-19 07:15:00 horse     234
 7     2 NA     2017-04-19 09:30:00 NA       6243
 8     2 male   2017-04-20 07:15:00 horse      NA
 9     2 male   2017-04-20 08:15:00 monkey     NA
10     3 NA     2017-08-19 08:15:00 NA         23
11     3 female 2017-08-20 23:15:00 fish       NA
12     3 NA     2017-08-21 06:30:00 NA        243
```

Comment: And thank you also for your patience. Now I noticed the contradiction you mentioned. I'll edit my question, so that it will be correct in case someone else has a smiliar problem.